# Loading R package iZID for simulating zero-inflated distribution

Tags: r-package

I am currently working on a project on zero-inflated models. I wish to simulate a sample of zero-inflated poisson distribution. When I type

```
  install.packages("iZID")
  library(iZID)
```

I got following error:

> ```
> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
> versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
> namespace 'foreach' 1.4.4 is already loaded, but >= 1.4.7 is required
> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'iZID'
> ```

Comment: Update package `foreach`